# tkcalendar throws AttributeError on get_date() method

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I want to get the selected date of a tkcalendar calendar but it throws an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_date'` and I don't know why.

Can somebody help me?

Here's my code:

```
class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        padding = 10

        # calenders
        mainCalendarFrame = Frame(root)


        # start
        startCalendarFrame = Frame(mainCalendarFrame)

        startLabel = Label(startCalendarFrame, text='Start').pack(fill=X, pady=(0, padding))
        self.startCalendar = Calendar(startCalendarFrame, selectmode='day', year=int(date.today().strftime('%Y')), month=int(date.today().strftime('%m')), day=int(date.today().strftime('%d'))).pack(fill=X, pady=(0, 5))


        mainCalendarFrame.pack(padx=padding, pady=padding)
        settingsFrame.pack(fill=X, padx=padding, pady=padding)
        btnCalculate.pack(fill=X, padx=padding, pady=padding)

    def btn_click(self):
        print(self.startCalendar.get_date())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Comment: Just like a widget, `Calendar` acts like a widget too, because it inherits from `Frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why it is not recommended to use the .pack(), .grid(), .place() methods immediately when defining a label because it returns None
You should split the command, and instead of what you did, proceed like this:

```
self.startCalendar = Calendar(...)
self.startCalendar.pack(...)
```

I had the same problem before and it was really annoying.